# What is the different between variable declared in class extension and variable in implementation class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

```
@interface TestViewController ()
{
    NSString *a;
}
@end

@implementation TestViewController
{
    NSString *b;
}
```

Seems like *a and *b are the same, both are private global variables in this file. 
Can anyone tell me there difference?

Answer (score 2):

Both are *instance variables*, not global variables, but otherwise the two declaration methods are the same. Being able to declare instance variables in the `@implementation` is a more recent feature of Objective-C and is the better location - instance variables are part of the implementation of a class and (generally) not part of the (public) interface.

Answer (score 0):

@properties declared in Class Extension in not visible in other classes.